# RegEx for excluding a word in a HTML attribute value

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a regex which matches and finds all `<a></a>` in my documents which i then loop thru and process. Below is what i use which works fine.

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

It matches all the below sample like

```
<a><img src="http://example.com/image-file.png"></a>
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">Click to Mail</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com#YahoosAnchor">blabla</a>
```

But i am wondering can the RegEx be modified to exclude any match for `<a href="mailto:`
as i dont want to process these ?

Comment: [Negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Try  `<a\b(?![^>]*href="mailto)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TdQ9ik/2)

Comment: Thanks that does the trick, one more question, is there a way to list multiple negative lookahead's ?

Comment: @NoSoup4you You can put them after each other or you can nest them. Do you have a use case for that?

Comment: in my case i parse docs for <A> tags, in some cases i dont want to get all of them since my code takes it and creates a translated url. So for example i want to also remove all links which have href="mailto as well as href="tel which is custom tag to go and initiate a call

Answer (score 0):

For the example data, one option could be to make use of a negative lookahead:

```
<a\b(?![^>]*href="mailto)[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

Another option could be to use a dom parser:

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
let html = `<a><img src="http://example.com/image-file.png"></a>
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">Click to Mail</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com#YahoosAnchor">blabla</a>`;
let doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
let anchors = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll("a"))
  .filter(a => !a.href.startsWith("mailto:"));

console.log(anchors);
```